# How to refer to size of json array in jsp tag

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I have a json array variable in a jsp file, referred to as ${jsonArray}

I also have a count variable, referred to as ${count}

I am trying  to write a conditional statement comparing the value of ${count} with the value of the length (number of objects) of ${jsonArray}.

The following compiles and works:

```
<c:if test="${count < 5}"> 
  ...do something 
</c:if>
```

however, this does not:

```
<c:if test="${count < jsonArray.length}">
  ...do something 
</c:if>
```

I know the syntax for the latter is incorrect, however I'm having a difficult time finding the correct way to accomplish this.

Any examples of how this could be achieved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<c:set>` to store the jsonArray.

```
<c:set var="jsonArrLength" value="${jsonArray.length}"></c:set>
```

Then:

```
<c:if test="${count < jsonArrLength}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mention which library are you using to generate JsonArray i assume that you are using `org.json.JSONArray` class to generate JsonArray for that

Change your code :

```
<c:if test="${count < jsonArray.length}">
  ...do something 
</c:if>
```

To

```
<c:if test="${count < jsonArray.length()}">
  ...do something 
</c:if>
```

If you are using [Gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) than it will different it has `.size()` function to find length of JsonArray  like below :

```
<c:if test="${count < jsonArray.size()}">
      ...do something 
</c:if>
```

If you are using another library please mention it. It is different for different library.